# Compare two populations by their means... t-test?

Tags: t-test, mean, population

I would like to have your opinion on the best way to compare two small sized populations of 13 and 14 individuals (but I have 3 tests for each individual on my dataset, so should I use 13 and 14 or 39 and 42?).

I have the values for 16 variables and the respective means and StDev for each variable and each population and I would like to compare them. I suppose comparing the means would be more appropriate, because the objective is to determine if the mean values are relevant to distinguish populations or not.

I did some research and I found that t-test is probably the most appropriate way to compare means for two small sized populations. However, I have some questions regarding t-test:

- Should I consider populations sizes as 13 and 14 or 39 and 42?
- Which formula of the t-test I should use (and which respective way of calculating degrees of freedom)?
- Should I use a one-tailed or two-tailed test (I know and understand the differences, I just would like to have an advise on which is better for this situation)?
- What value of alpha level should I choose and why?

Here's the data, if it helps in any way:

[image]

Thank you